# Change the access modifier in runtime

Tags: c#, reflection, access-modifiers

Solely for the sake of example I've written this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int MyMethod()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Is there **any** way to change access modifier of `MyClass::MyMethod()` in runtime to *public* using Reflection or something else and then invoke it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not really sure if you can modify the access specifier, but you can call the private method through reflection like:

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass();
MethodInfo yourMethod = instance
                            .GetType()
                            .GetMethod("MyMethod", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var returnValue = yourMethod.Invoke(instance, new object[] { });
Console.WriteLine(returnValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

No, a class is what it is and you can't change it at runtime.

You could create a new class that has the members, except that `MyMethod` would be public, but it wouldn't be the same class anymore.

In any case, I can't think of any situation where doing something like this would make any kind of sense.