# Show or hide functions in a class based on which constructor used in C#

Tags: c#

Consider the following class

```
public class DataManager
{
  private SqlConnection cn;
  public SqlCommand cmd;

  public DataManager(bool initializeCmd=true)
  {
    string conString="server=192.168.1.20;User Id=sa;pwd=123;Persist Security Info=True; database=testDB";       
    cn = new SqlConnection(conString);
    if (initializeCmd)
      cmd = new SqlCommand();            
  }
  public void OpenDbConnection()
  {
    if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
      cn.Open();            
  }       
  public void CloseDbConnection()
  {
    if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
      cn.Close();
  }
  public bool Update_Database()
  {
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    OpenDbConnection();
    int n=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    CloseDbConnection();
    if(n>0) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
  }
  public bool Update_Database(string cmdTxt, bool isProcedure)
  {   
    cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdTxt, cn);
    if (isProcedure)
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    else
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    OpenDbConnection();
    int n=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    CloseDbConnection();
    if(n>0) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
  }            
}
```

Now consider 2nd class

```
public class staff
{
  DataManager dm;
  public bool resetPwd(string code)
    {
        dm = new DataManager(false);
        string query= "UPDATE Staff WHERE pwd='123' WHERE code="+code;            
        return dm.Update_Database(query,false);
    }
    public bool changePwd(string code,string pwd)
    {
        dm = new DataManager();
        dm.cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Staff WHERE pwd=@pwd WHERE code=@code";
        dm.cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        dm.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", code);
        dm.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", code);
        return dm.Update_Database();
    }
}
```

DataManager class is a common class for handling Database operations. Now my question is whether there is any way to prevent me from using

```
Update_Database()
```

function if i calls

```
dm = new DataManager(false)
```

instead of

```
dm = new DataManager()
```

from staff class. Because if i use dm = new DataManager(false) , it will throw an error since the sql command object is not initialized.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the access modifier in runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325361/change-the-access-modifier-in-runtime)

Comment: You got good answers already but this implementation has so much smell in it that I'd suggest you open new question with same code about 'how to improve my current data access implementation'...

Answer (score 2):

Nothing can stop others from initializing `dm = new DataManager(true)`. If you need database updating not available, then move it from `DataManager`. Create another `DatabaseUpdater` class which will be responsible for database update operations. Note: names of `Update` methods are misleading - they supposed to execute UPDATE queries, but I can pass DELETE query text, and execute it.

BTW usefulness of `DataManager` is arguable. ADO.NET uses [connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399543(v=vs.110).aspx) to minimize cost of opening connections. Also hard-coding connection strings is not very good idea. Use connectionStrings section of config file to provide them.

I would suggest you to take a look on [Dapper](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) library, which will make your code look like this:

```
public bool ChangePassword(string code, string pwd)
{
    using(DbConnection conn = GetConnection())
    {
        string sql = "UPDATE Staff SET pwd=@pwd WHERE code=@code";
        int updatedRowsCount = conn.Query<int>(sql, new { code, pwd }).First();
        return updatedRowsCount == 1;
    }
}
```

Connection will be opened and closed automatically. Command will be created, and all parameters will be added to command. I haven't provided `GetConnection` implementation - it's responsibility to read connection string and return new connection.

And last suggestion - avoid methods which accept boolean parameters. This kind of parameters very confusing. What `DataManager(true)` means? How it differs from `DataManager(false)`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "show and hide" functions automatically. Once your code compiles, it cannot be dynamically changed.

What you can do, which is not so "neat" is either throw an exception or not run the code at all. This is very poor interface design because it creates behavior that cannot be understood easily.

If you really want to, you can setup your DataManager to receive the database connection string:

```
 string connectionString = "...";
 DataManager dm = new DataManager(connectionString);
```

if the implementor does not know the connection string, they will not be able to open a connection.

This isn't the "best design" but it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution maybe to just expose a bool property for if the command is available. That way, the consumer can test first if the method is permitted. If they still want to call it then throw an exception.

The important thing is that they have the means to test for themselves.

.NET 4.5 possibly 4, introduced the dynamic class object which can have changing methods at runtime. I would not want to use it this way in my code, but it is there.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check if `initializeCmd == true` before executing the `Update_Database()` (from inside the function). Do a NOP if it's value is `false` (just return). You could initialize the `SqlCommand` to a default value so that calling the method won't have any side effects. Or check if your command is null before execution. You also could use inheritance for different specialized class behaviour.

EDIT:
The library [Code Contracts for .NET](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1ec7db13-3363-46c9-851f-1ce455f66970) could help you displaying warnings depending on how class is used if you don't like `#warning`.

> Code Contracts are static library methods used from any .NET program to specify the code’s behavior.

Using the library enables you to use static checking to check for contract violations. (If you really think that this is neccessary!)

Comment: Right now i am using that method. my doubt is whether i can generate a compile time error message just like setting obsolete attribute with false value!!!

Comment: I think this not supported nativley. You can generate a level one warning (see: #warning (C# Reference) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/963th5x3.aspx). You rather should use an overloaded constructor which defines the behaviozur of the class. Like default constructor fro default behaviour and wenn used with a SqlCommand it behaves different... This way the different behaviour is more clear to the user of the class.